# Why am I getting a positive result with fractional powers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sign

The following output from IDLE makes no sense to me.

```
>>> a=-1.0
>>> a**(1/3)
1.0
>>> a==-1.0
True
>>> -1.0**(1/3)
-1.0
```

Why are two theoretically equivalent statements returning different results? How is Python (2.7) handling the `__pow__` method for doubles that this is the result? I just tried it with integers as well and received the same result. Other than computing the sign of the input to the `__pow__` function and copying it to the result, how can I fix this?

Comment: operator precedence. `-1 * (1 ** (1/3))`. See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: "positive result with fractional powers" What you are doing here is not fractional power. Try `1.0/3` and compare it to `1/3`.

Comment: Ouch. That was a silly mistake on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an operator precendence issue:

```
>>> -1.0**(1/3)
-1.0
>>> (-1.0)**(1/3)
1.0
```

Also, note that `(1/3)` is zero unless you import `division` from the `__future__`, which gives Python 3.x behavior (and a `ValueError`). Use `1/3.` to get 1/3 as a float.

Comment: Not to mention `1/3` is `0`.

Comment: @Pavel Anossov Oh, right. I'm used to 3.3 but I'm using 2.7 for work.

Comment: don't forget ... `(-1.0)**(.333)` is a `ValueError` as the result is necessarily complex... To get that to work, you'd need `(-1.+0j)**(.3333)`

Comment: Or you can do `1.0/3` or `float(1)/3`.